# DataGridView ScrollBars are not working after Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, scroll, datagridview

I'm setting a dataTable as data source of a datagridview. I do this on a new thread (I don't want my UI blocked while is loading data).
My dilema is: the scrollbars are not working after the thread finishes. I tryed setting Scrollbars.None before load the data, and Scrollbars.Both after. Also tryed with Refresh. But only helped me to show the scrollbars, these still without working.

If I use the same code in my principal, thread it works perfectly.

so how can I do to make it work?

My code:

```
private void PressKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var process = new Thread(this.LoadData);
        process.Start();
    }

private void LoadData()
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        this.dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
        this.dgv.Columns.Clear();
        this.dgv.DataSource = MyDataTable;
        this.dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
    }
```

Comment: post your code to get answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it. I used MethodInvoker inside of my thread. It allows me run on UI thread and update the controls:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    this.dgv.Columns.Clear();
    this.dgv.DataSource = MyDataTable;

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both; // runs on UI thread
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! In my case today I also had to set `ScrollBars` to `None`, and then after I'd had my fun with changing `DataSource` I would set `ScrollBars` back to my desired value (`Vertical`). Just leaving this here for other people to see.

Answer (score 0):

I think the UI and datasource binding of DataGridView are not in the same thread. So its UI cannot aware that the datasource has been bind.
Could you try that: implement the delegate for DataBindingComplete with setting the ScrollBars to Both?

For example:

```
private void dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    this.dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
}
```

The document: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the same. ScrollBars are shown but they're not working. They stay static when I try scroll the dgv

Comment: I have tried to create an application by your code. It seems the scrollbars visible but disabled. I think the scrollbars are created in the "process" thread, and it doesn't work with dgv in the main thread. I don't have any solution right now, will get back if I have.

Comment: You're right, the scrollbars are created on second thread. But I already fix that, and finally works. I used MethodInvoker delegate to set ScrollBars.Both on main thread. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to do UI operations in UI thread to take effect.

```
//UI Thread
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    //DataGridview Refreshment
    dataGridView.Enabled = true;
    dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joel added to DannSahn's answer, you must set the scrollbars properties to none, using the invoke method will set them up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).