# scrollbars not working in datagridview using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, scrollbar

I built an app that fills a datagridview by pulling data from different stored procedures(SQL Server) into a DataTable.

When the datagridview is filled, I can scroll down using my mouse, but the vertical and horizontal scrollbars along with the "up/down/left/right" buttons are greyed out, clicking on them has no effect.

I've tried multiple solutions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573969/c-sharp-datagridview-doesnt-show-scrollbars-when-filling-from-task) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209841/datagridview-scrollbars-are-not-working-after-thread) without any luck.

At the initial stages of the code they were showing correctly, this began to happen after I decided to fill the datagridview using Threads (I wanted to have a nice "loading" GIF displayed while the stored procedure executes, mostly because some stored procedures take several minutes to execute, depending on the amount of that that is required).

Here's a fragment of my code:

```
    public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Enabled = false;
        pbLSearching.Visible = true;       // I used Threads just so I can display this one
        lblExecutingQuery.Visible = true;  // along with this.

        startDate = dtpStartDate.Text;     // These are my parameters needed for the  
        endDate = dtpEndDate.Text;         // stored procedures

        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;   // These two are here to clear it out when I 
        dataGridView1.Refresh();           // run a different search

        if (tabSearchOptions.SelectedTab == tabSearchOptions.TabPages["tabSearchByStation"])
        {            
        Thread dataThread = new Thread(getData);
        dataThread.Start();              
        }
    }   
   
    public void getData()
    {
        
        if (FTS1 == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = FTS_1.GetFunctionalData(startDate, endDate);
           
        }
        else if (FTS2 == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = FTS_2.GetFunctionalData(startDate, endDate);
        }
         .
         .
         .
         // and so on for the rest of the stations and some unrelated code
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out that the solution was actually [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209841/datagridview-scrollbars-are-not-working-after-thread), as someone replied to the answer, I had to set the scrollbars properties to "none" then using Invoke inside my thread would set them up

Comment: The solution is NOT to set properties of Controls from a Thread other than the UI Thread. If you have synchronous code, run and await a Task that returns a value you use as the DataSource of your DGV instead of starting a Thread. -- If, for some reason, you think that you need to set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` somewhere, that's undeniable proof that your code needs to be rewritten. That property suppresses the warnings, it doesn't remove the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This was a code that was already working and I know I broke something when I decided to add a "loading" GIF while the stored procedure is ran, I did this after seeing someone getting desperate and clicking randomly in the app and causing it to crash. if it counts as a way to defend myself... this is the second C# I write, and the first one using datagridvews, and I have not released this "fix" for production use yet; I will definitely consider re-writing stuff.